# Setting a big notification icon not working in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to show a big icon on the right side of a notification from a composable, but getting a type mismatch error, but I am using a `.png` image:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but Bitmap? was expected
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
@Composable
fun NotificationApp() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val channelId = "MyTestChannel"
    val notificationId = 0

    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_edit_location) 
        .setContentTitle("My Test Notification")
        .setContentText("This is my test notification in one line...")
        .setLargeIcon(R.drawable.header) // error here
        .setStyle(
            NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText(
                    "This is my test notification in one line. Made it longer " +
                            "by setting the setStyle property. " +
                            "It should not fit in one line anymore, " +
                            "rather show as a longer notification content."
                )
        )
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

    createNotificationChannel(channelId, context)

    with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)) {
        notify(notificationId, builder.build())
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method [`setLargeIcon`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#setLargeIcon(android.graphics.Bitmap)) works with a `Bitmap`.

You can use:

```
.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources,R.drawable.header))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!! Any tips on how to make the icon circular?